# Rolling and cumulative standard deviation in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

Is there a vectorized operation to calculate the cumulative and rolling standard deviation (SD) of a Python DataFrame?

For example, I want to add a column 'c' which calculates the cumulative SD based on column 'a', i.e. in index 0, it shows NaN due to 1 data point, and in index 1, it calculates SD based on 2 data points, and so on.

The same question goes to rolling SD too. Is there an efficient way to calculate without iterating through df.itertuples()?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def main():
    np.random.seed(123)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
    print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 16):

For cumulative SD base on columna 'a', let's use `rolling` with a windows size the length of the dataframe and `min_periods = 2`:

```
df['a'].rolling(len(df),min_periods=2).std()
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c
0 -1.085631  0.997345       NaN
1  0.282978 -1.506295  0.967753
2 -0.578600  1.651437  0.691916
3 -2.426679 -0.428913  1.133892
4  1.265936 -0.866740  1.395750
5 -0.678886 -0.094709  1.250335
6  1.491390 -0.638902  1.374933
7 -0.443982 -0.434351  1.274843
8  2.205930  2.186786  1.450563
9  1.004054  0.386186  1.403721
```

And for rolling SD based on two values at a time:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].rolling(2).std()
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c
0 -1.085631  0.997345       NaN
1  0.282978 -1.506295  0.967753
2 -0.578600  1.651437  0.609228
3 -2.426679 -0.428913  1.306789
4  1.265936 -0.866740  2.611073
5 -0.678886 -0.094709  1.375197
6  1.491390 -0.638902  1.534617
7 -0.443982 -0.434351  1.368514
8  2.205930  2.186786  1.873771
9  1.004054  0.386186  0.849855
```

Comment: This is the wrong solution

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant  Can you explain?  I am not disagreeing with you, just that it would help if you explained what is wrong.

Comment: Well you are using the wrong function - a rolling function - but this isn't a rolling operation. The correct function to use here is the expanding function

Answer (score 7):

I think, if by rolling you mean cumulative, then the right term in Pandas is `expanding`:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html#pandas.DataFrame.expanding

It also accepts a `min_periods` argument.

```
df['c'] = df['a'].expanding(2).std()
```

The case for `rolling` was handled by Scott Boston, and it is unsurprisingly called `rolling` in Pandas.

The advantage if `expanding` over `rolling(len(df), ...)` is, you don't need to know the `len` in advance. It is very useful e.g. in `groupby` dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `expanding` in combination with `std`:

The correct solution to this problem is to use the `expanding()` function in combination with `std()`, which you are already familiar with.

This example includes how to use the improved generators.

```
rng = numpy.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(10, 2)), columns=['a', 'b'])

# Calculate cumulative variance for each column
cumulative_variance_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.expanding().var())
```

If you want the variance data to be in the same dataframe there are many different methods to do that either append the columns or use the apply function on a per column basis.